# Should we salvage old (highly upvoted) questions instead of deleting them?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, old-questions, historical-lock

I noticed there are a lot of 'older' (2009-2010) questions getting closed (and voted for deletion). I find deletion a bit harsh since most of them contain interesting content imho. They stem from a time with a different rule set where these types of questions were allowed to thrive (in CW form, that is)...

Some examples:

- [Questions every good Java/Java EE Developer should be able to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-java-ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer)
- [What should 'Computer Science' be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345080/what-should-computer-science-be-called)
- [Questions every good Database/SQL developer should be able to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119859/questions-every-good-database-sql-developer-should-be-able-to-answer)

Why not simply "lock" (for historical purposes) every one of these questions (when they have had 150+ upvotes, for example) instead of deleting them?

Comment: It's not a different ruleset, it was just users not wanting to draw the line already mentioned in the scope

Comment: @random: I beg to differ. In 2009 - 2010 different types of questions now routinely routed to programmers.stackexchange or others were possible in CW form on SO without getting closed. Code-Golf was even `officially` accepted by meta until codegolf.stackexchange.com saw the light of day. I feel we collectively became *a lot* stricter in our definition of what an acceptable question is here (I do realize that may have been necessary because of SO's enormous growth)...

Comment: Those questions are not all that interesting.  The first and third posts are [interview-questions], which almost everyone agrees don't belong on the site at all, and the second one is a hypothetical vocabulary lesson.  Who cares?

Comment: The "should be able to answer" questions are a slippery slope. [This Ruby one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5265846/102937) was migrated to Programmers, and then promptly closed and deleted there.

Comment: @RoberHarvey: I tend to agree that those 3 are not the hidden gems worth preserving. There's a case to be made for consistency too. The first interview question in my example is near deletion, the second one is locked. I imagine the same applies for historical code golf questions too (some get deleted, others get locked, others are still open)... What may be worthwile preserving for one mod might be `delete` material for another. Maybe it's an idea to start a meta thread to discuss questions eligible for deletion and / or locking?

Comment: @Christophe - This has been asked before, several times. One thing to ask oneself is "Why are these old questions valuable, when similar new questions will be heavily downvoted and deleted?". If I was allowed to ask "What should every C++ programmer know", it might also get 150 upvotes and 42 answers in 3-4 years, but will now be deleted within 3-4 hours (or minutes :-). What's the difference? Why are old bad questions more valuable than new bad questions?

Answer (score 3):

The best place for these might be a blog as they aren't questions in the sense that Stack Exchange (now) understands.

It's a shame there isn't an SO community blog, but in the absence of that it might be worth asking over on [meta.programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com) to see if they'd be good posts for [our blog](http://blog.programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Not Programmers! Oh, uh, hello Chris.